# Azure B2c how to prevent user to login till admin approve

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have created a custom claim "is approved" and set it to false while users signup.
what I need to to do is to prevent users from login based on this attribute and show an error message "your account is under review please try again once the account is approved"

how can I accomplish this using B2C custom policy

also, I tried to set "accountEnabled" to false but in signup always getting account is locked error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the technical profile for sign in, after calling login-NonInteractive, You can try reading the user using the object id. So read the flag "is approved". If It's set to false, write a claim transformation technical profile to assert the "is approved" value and throw an error.[image]

[Claim Transformation - Boolean Assert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/boolean-transformations#assertbooleanclaimisequaltovalue)

[Use Claim Transformation technical profile in validation technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile#use-a-validation-technical-profile)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use the [“Paragraph” user input type](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/creating-an-error-page-for-an-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy-flow-fb2692a3b50f) that gets triggered by a precondition.